# Running R code for EM Algorithm

Tags: statistics

I am new to using R for statistical purposes. My question involves finding the EM algorithm for a normal distribution. I have the following code:

```
#Normal mixture. 
# Generate data from normal mixture 
#w=0.7, mu_1=0, sigma^2_1=1, mu_2=1, sigma^2_2=2.
#Set the seed, so computations are reproducible.
set.seed(4)
n<-300
w<-0.7
mu1<-0
sigma21<-1
mu2<-5
sigma22<-2
x<-ifelse(runif(n)<w,rnorm(n,mu1,sqrt(sigma21)),rnorm(n,mu2,sqrt(sigma22)))
#Initialize.
theta.k<-.1
theta.kp1<-.5
#Then loop over the following
theta.k<-theta.kp1
tmp<-theta.k*dnorm(x,mu1,sqrt(sigma21))
ehat.k<-tmp/(tmp+(1-theta.k)*dnorm(x,mu2,sqrt(sigma22)))
theta.kp1<-mean(ehat.k)
```

I tried running i but nothing came out. I was wondering what I did wrong and what I need to do to fix it.

Comment: To me this looks like pseudo-code rather than like actual R code. $\qquad$

Comment: I wonder if this would get better answers at stats.stackexchange.com? $\qquad$